# multi-line regex with groups python

Tags: python, regex, multiline

looking for some assistance from regex experts for my below requirement. I have a string of the format

```
if (x==True) then
    operation1
end
if (y==False) then
    operation2
    operation3
end
if (z==1) then
   operation4
end
```

I'm looking for this multiline string to be divided into groups as below.

```
('x==True', 'operation1')
('y==False', 'operation2', 'operation3')
('z==1', 'operation4')
```

Comment: much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
reg = r"if\s+\((.*?)\)\s+then\s(.*?)end"
match = re.findall(reg, text, re.DOTALL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
if\s+\(([^)]+)\)\s+then\s+([\s\S]+?)end
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

[Click to view](https://regex101.com/r/eV8iD6/1)

Comment: Just great! Works for me. I had to tweak it a bit to make it work with parentheses inside the if condition

Comment: @SaLo Don't forget to accept the most helpful answer in your eyes.

Answer (score 0):

A funny way with the [parse](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parse) module:

```
import re
from parse import *

s='''if (x==True) then
    operation1
end
if (y==False) then
    operation2
    operation3
end
if (z==1) then
   operation4
end'''

for block in re.split(r'(?<=\nend)\n', s):
    m = parse("if ({}) then\n{}\nend", block)
    print(tuple([m[0]]+m[1].strip().split()))
```